# Excel Use ISERROR with check for FALSE in an OR statement without returning an error

Tags: microsoft-excel

Column A contains data which for each row has one of three possibilities:

TRUE, FALSE or the "#N/A" error.

Column B is required that returns 1 if the value in Column A is either FALSE or "#N/A#" error and returns 0 otherwise.

The following formula is used:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(A1),NOT(A1)),1,0)
```

However this returns the error "#N/A" wherever the value in column A is "#N/A". Breaking the formula down:

```
=ISERROR(A1) returns 1 when A1 is "#N/A".
=IF(NOT(A1),1,0) returns "#N/A" when A1 is "#N/A".
```

As such the issue appears to be that "NOT" check is returns an error whenever the value in column A is an error. Further this is superseding the 1 returned by "ISERROR(A1)".

Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good explanation, but I suggest a bit shorter formulas:

```
=IFERROR(1-A1,0)
```

or

```
=IFNA(1-A1,0)
```

or if you need to use `ISERROR` function:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1),0,1-A1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the error when you have <kbd>NA()</kbd> using <kbd>IFNA()</kbd> or <kbd>IFERROR()</kbd>. The following screenshot shows the steps

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=ISERROR(A2)+IFNA(NOT(A2),0)
```

---

Or,

```
=ISNA(A2)+IFNA(NOT(A2),0)
```

---

• With <kbd>IF()</kbd> and <kbd>OR()</kbd>

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(A2),IFNA(NOT(A2),1)),1,0)
```

Instead of using an <kbd>IF()</kbd> with <kbd>OR()</kbd> I did a <kbd>BOOLEAN LOGIC</kbd> operation where `+` denotes the <kbd>OR()</kbd> to return `TRUE` which is `1` while `FALSE` is `0`.

Your formula is not working because when there is a <kbd>NA()</kbd> it cant detect the error, you need to use <kbd>IFNA()</kbd> or <kbd>IFERROR()</kbd> even <kbd>ISNA()</kbd> parses the error bt it will return `0` since if the first is not an error --> `=ISERROR(A2)` it returns `FALSE` i.e. `0` again when there is not an error --> `=ISNA(A2)` it returns also `0` ie. `0+0 =0`.(refer last screenshot).

[image]

---

[image]

---

And I would suggest you to always try to evaluate the formulas, `Excel` has some built in features which helps a lot, like the evaluating the formulas. It is under <kbd>Formulas</kbd> Tab --> Grouped by <kbd>Formula Auditing</kbd> Click --> <kbd>Evaluate Formula</kbd>

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is 0 if TRUE, or 1 if N/A or FALSE.

If column A won't contain anything else than these three, the easiest formula is this:

```
=IF(A1=TRUE;0;1)
```

This means: If A1 is TRUE, then 0, if anything else, then 1.

Given that this will also create a 1 for empty cells, you can add the following:

```
=IF( A1="" ; "" ; IF(A1=TRUE;0;1) )
```

This basically means: If A1 is empty, then return empty. However, if not, then we evaluate IF A1 = True, if so, return 0, otherwise 1.